# Not able to request OSM Buildings with python

Tags: python, request, gis, openstreetmap

When trying an osm buildings link in the browser it works fine, but when using a python request it goes really slow and does not return the expected JSON.

For example, with this URL: https://a.data.osmbuildings.org/0.2/anonymous/tile/15/16111/10612.json

Using the following code:

```
import requests

buildings_data_url = "https://a.data.osmbuildings.org/0.2/anonymous/tile/15/16111/10612.json"
request = requests.get(buildings_data_url)
print(request.content)
```

returns

```
b''
```

And `request.json()` returns error because of the wrong format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSM Buildings servers are denying GET requests with HTTP header `'user-agent': 'python-requests/xxx'`, which is the default user-agent value for python `requests` module.

Adjust user-agent value in your headers to represent one of the commonly used browsers. For example, Chrome user-agent value is `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36`

Here is what worked for me:

```py
import requests

def config():
    url = "https://data.osmbuildings.org/0.2/anonymous/tile/15/9339/12531.json"
    agentheader={'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.28.4'}
    return url,agentheader

url, agentheader = config()

response = requests.get(url,headers = agentheader)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

From time to time OSM Building servers will respond with a 404 due to request throttling. Watch out for that and have your code retry.

Comment: This worked for me for a few months but now I get response 429 with no Retry-after header, even after waiting a day... did they change something on their end?